# Please identify organ

Tags: zoology, anatomy, organs

[image]

This is the gut area of an Eastern Grey Kangaroo taken of a property in the Southern Highlands of NSW, Australia. The top red organ appears to be the spleen but what is the elongated tubular organ extending from the spleen? Is it a deformation or the result of disease?

Comment: You are aware that *all* species of kangaroo are [protected](http://www.environment.nsw.gov.au/animals/Livingwithkangaroos.htm)?

Comment: You mean the long red "tube"? At a guess I'd say it just looks like a lobe of the spleen.

Comment: Thank you vervet for your response and thank you for clarifying the issue with AliceD. This kangaroo was taken on a cattle farm under the following provision: http://www.environment.nsw.gov.au/wildlifelicences/OccupierLicences.htm

Comment: An evidence? http://www.appendicitis.pro/the-sir-frederick-treves/sir-frederick-treves/the-dissection-drawings-of/brush-tailed-kangaroo-gi.html

Answer (score 3):

As far as it can be deducted from the picture you ask about [Appendix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appendix_(anatomy)) or just [Coecum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cecum). This is a normal finding and not abnormal one. (You can see a terminal [Ileum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ileum) as well).
If other pictures were provided it could be possible to give more exact answer.

[image]

Comment: I don't know if the question is asking about this organ or the extention of the spleen. But in any case here is some information on the kangaroo "appendix": http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1420-9101.2009.01809.x/full It's perhaps more blown up than it would be in a living animal, but that's probably a post mortem change as there's still living bacteria in the GI tract producing gas.

Comment: I was under the impression that macropods did not have an appendix